# sql server duplicate ID's update other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I was working on a task to update columns which have duplicate ID's in a column 
[image: screenshot]

how can we update column only DrugLabelName ? i need to update old_drug_name with new_drug_name using the duplicate ID 00004029830 ?

Please advise

Comment: How do you know which is the old and which is the new?

Comment: Are the old names always going to have a lower INTid?

Comment: we will know the old and new based on INTid, if a record has max INTid , then it is newer

Comment: Your design is not normalised. Why are you storing the drug label name in that table if it is functionally dependent on ID?

Comment: yes, it will have lower INTid for old_drugs

Answer (score 1):

If you want all rows with the same `id` to have the same name, you can use window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             first_value(druglabelname) over (partition by id order by intid desc) as new_druglabelname
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set druglabelname = new_druglabelname
    where druglabelname <> new_druglabelname;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
     CREATE TABLE tbl
        (INTid int 
        ,ID varchar (20)
        ,DrugLabelName varchar(200)
        )

    INSERT tbl (INTid, ID, DrugLabelName)
    SELECT  137272, '00004029830', 'old_drug_name'

    INSERT tbl (INTid, ID, DrugLabelName)
    SELECT  1668177, '00004029830', 'New_drug_name'

    INSERT tbl (INTid, ID, DrugLabelName)
    SELECT 1668178, '00004029831', 'Other_drug_name'

    GO

    UPDATE t
    SET DrugLabelName = x.DrugLabelName
    FROM tbl AS t
    INNER JOIN tbl as x
        ON t.ID = x.id
        AND x.INTid > t.INTid

    SELECT *
    FROM tbl

    DROP TABLE tbl
```